# Trying to create a program that tracks which inputs I've added but stuck

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, counter

Basically I'm trying to get my program to loop back to main_screen after entering a screen_number, repeating indefinitely until I press T to terminate it. Meanwhile P is supposed to track how many numbers I've imputed throughout the session. This is what I have so far and I only know how to loop screen_number. Just can't figure out how to loop back to main_screen or how to go about making the "P" function.

````
main_screen = str(input("Pick W to add a new number, P to show how many numbers, high or low, have been added, or T to terminate: "))
if(main_screen == "W"):
    screen_number = int(input("Input your grade: "))    
    if(screen_number >= 10):
        print("It's high.")
    elif(user_grade < 10):
        print("It's low.")
if(user_menu == "T"):
    print("Terminating system.")
else:
    print("Invalid.")```
````

Comment: You could try to envelop your code into a [while loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) and put a [break](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_break.asp) on the T input.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list and store the values in it for "P". Use `while` loop for returning to `main_screen`.

```
l = []
while True:
    main_screen = input("Pick W to add a new number, P to show how many numbers, high or low, have been added, or T to terminate: ")
    if (main_screen == "W"):
        screen_number = int(input("Input your grade: "))    
        if (screen_number >= 10):
            print("It's high.")
        elif (user_grade < 10):
            print("It's low.")
        l.append(screen_number)
    elif (user_menu == "T"):
        print("Terminating system.")
        break
    elif (user_menu == "P"):
        print(f"No. of numbers is {len(l)}")
    else:
        print("Invalid.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping with a condition and break when the correct input is entered:

```
while True:
    main_screen = str(input("Pick W to add a new number, P to show how many numbers, 
    high or low, have been added, or T to terminate: "))
    if(main_screen == "W"):
        screen_number = int(input("Input your grade: "))    
    if(screen_number >= 10):
        print("It's high.")
    elif(user_grade < 10):
        print("It's low.")
    if(user_menu == "T"):
        print("Terminating system.")
        return
    else:
        print("Invalid.")
```

Comment: You can use the `{}` button in the editor to format selected lines as code. Technically it just puts 4 spaces in front of lines, so that works too.

Comment: Remark on the code itself: `return` only works inside functions (and also ends not just the loop, but everything afterwards), `break` may be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while True:
    main_screen = input("Pick W to add a new number\nP to show how many numbers high or low have been added\nT to terminate: ")
    if main_screen == "W":
        user_grade = int(input("Input your grade: "))    
        if user_grade >= 10:
            print("It's high.")
        elif user_grade < 10:
            print("It's low.")
    elif main_screen == "T":
        print("Terminating system.")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid.")
```